# SQL Server : select where row was X but is not now X

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
WOTranID   WOID   Status      DateCreated
----------------------------------------------
1          5      Ready        6/6/2015
2          5      Pending      6/5/2015
3          7      Pending      6/9/2015
4          8      Scheduled    6/10/2015
```

What I need is to select all WOID where the status was pending but is not currently pending.

Thank you for your help.

Edit: Using the example table above I would only like to return WOID 5.

Comment: What does this mean `status was pending but is not currently pending`?

Comment: Meaning that the latest status (defined by newest Datecreated) is not Pending, but that Pending was at one point the newest status. For example: " where 'Pending' In (Status) " is valid, but not enough to satisfy my requirements as I need to exclude records where the Status is only Pending

Comment: For the given data, you have no such examples.  Can you edit the question and provide data that would be returned by your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, select all WOIDs which have had a status of pending, then intersect that with the list of WOIDs whose current status is not pending (using `row_number()` to select the latest status per WOID).

```
(Select Distinct WOID
from MyTable
where Status = 'Pending')

intersect 

(Select WOID
from
  (Select WOID
    , Status
    , Row_number() over (partition by WOID order by DateCreated desc) as RN
  from MyTable) a
where Status <> 'Pending' and RN = 1)
```

Comment: Awsome. I think that makes just enough sense for me to give it a go. Thank you, and thanks for the formatting assist. Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

May be this:

```
select distinct t1.WOID 
from TableName t1 
where Status <> 'Pending' and 
not exists(select * from TableName t2 
           where t2.WOID = t1.WOID and t2.DateCreated > t1.DateCreated) and
exists(select * from TableName t3 
       where t3.WOID = t1.WOID and t3.DateCreated < t1.DateCreated and t3.Status = 'Pending')
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you want the next `woid` that changes from pending.  If you want all of them, then you should clarify the question.

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use the `lag()` function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(status) over (partition by woid order by datecreated) as prev_status
      from table t
     ) t
where prev_status = 'Pending' and status <> 'Pending';
```

You can do something similar in earlier versions use `cross apply`.

Comment: Will this still work if an item can go from "pending" to "not pending" and back to "pending" again?  Unclear from the question if this is possible in the data.

Comment: It is impossible to move from Pending to another status and then back to Pending.

Comment: @APH . . . This would get every case where such a transition occurred.